# Unexpected output when appending dict to list

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, google-analytics

I have written a small API in Python 2.7 that retrieves data from google analytics and sends it to my own website.

This is the input

```
{'country': '(not set)', 'visits': '1'}
{'country': 'Belgium', 'visits': '9'}
{'country': 'Brazil', 'visits': '2'}
{'country': 'Germany', 'visits': '2'}
{'country': 'Mexico', 'visits': '2'}
{'country': 'Netherlands', 'visits': '38'}
{'country': 'Philippines', 'visits': '1'}
{'country': 'Portugal', 'visits': '1'}
{'country': 'Spain', 'visits': '1'}
{'country': 'Thailand', 'visits': '1'}
{'country': 'United Kingdom', 'visits': '1'}
{'country': 'United States', 'visits': '1'}
```

When i append this to a list with the following code:

```
new_dict = {}
new_list = []
for row in query:
    for count, attribute in enumerate(list_of_dim_met):    
        new_dict.update({
            attribute.replace('ga:',''): row[count].encode('ascii','ignore')
            })
    new_list.append(new_dict)
print new_list
```

it only repeats the last row with united states 12 times. I have tried everything but I am getting crazy. Anybody got a clue?

Kind regards.

Comment: You're filling `new_list` with multiple references to *the exact same dictionary object*. Move `new_dict = ` **inside** the `for` loop...

Comment: I feel so stupid now. Thank you for the fast and good response

Answer (score 1):

Because the code is using the same dictionary in the loop and updating the dictinoary, and append the same dictionary into the list.

Make a new dictionary in a loop instead of using the same dictionary.

```
new_list = []
for row in query:
    for count, attribute in enumerate(list_of_dim_met):    
        new_dict = {
            attribute.replace('ga:',''): row[count].encode('ascii','ignore')
        }
    new_list.append(new_dict)
```